# Complicated Contact Form Submit (ajax help)

Tags: php, ajax, forms, contacts, contact-form

How can I run this contact form without reloading or changing the page on submit? I was told to use ajax but I don't know where to start with that.

I would like to be able to display the output ('Successfully sent! Thank you.') on my index.html inside a div for example.

```
<?php if (isset($_POST["contact"])){

$to  = 'contact@example.com';       //Contact Email

$from  = $_POST["email"];
$name = $_POST["name"];
$message = $_POST["message"];

// subject
$subject = 'New message from '.$name;


// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'To: ' .$to. "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: '.$from . "\r\n";

// Mail it
if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
    echo "Successfully sent! Thank you.";
} else {
    echo "Oops! Failed to send your message";
}

}

?>
```

Comment: You may like start with www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp

Comment: Here is a really good source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX

I don't like W3Schools, MDN is pretty much the "go-to" for most developers. Anyways, what happens is that via JavaScript you'll POST to a page and receive a response.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below codes =)

html

```
<form id="contactform" name="contactform" method="post" action="email.php">
<div>
    <input type="text" name="name">
</div>
<div>
    <input type="email" name="email">
</div>
<div>
    <input type="text" name="subject">
</div>
<div>
    <textarea name="message"></textarea>
</div>
    <button type="submit">
        Send Message
    </button>
</form>
```

ajax

```
var form = $('#contactform');
form.submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var form_status = $('<div></div>');
    $.ajax({
        type:"post",
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        beforeSend: function(){
            form.prepend( form_status.html('<p>Sending</p>').fadeIn() );
        }
    }).done(function(data){
        form_status.html('<p>Done</p>').delay(3000).fadeOut();
    });
});
```

email.php

```
<?php 

$to  = 'contact@example.com';       //Contact Email

$from  = $_POST["email"];
$name = $_POST["name"];
$message = $_POST["message"];

// subject
$subject = 'New message from '.$name;


// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'To: ' .$to. "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: '.$from . "\r\n";

// Mail it
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

?>
```

Comment: How do I put the div properly into my html to call the php response? Right now when I click submit it opens a blank page.

Comment: what is the url of the blank page?